# How to transfer photos from Google Drive to Google Photos

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Is there a way to transfer some photos/videos from Google Drive to Google Photos (same account) without the need to download all the files and then uploading them again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try enabling in Drive settings - "Automatically put you Google Photos into a folder in My Drive". This will show Google Photos folder. Try copying there some photos and check a bit later if they will be shown in Google Photos. Can't promise though :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I realize I cannot do that if I use work/school account. That's why I wasn't being able to find anything related. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

its as simple as uploading images from your phone to google photos

1. On your computer, go to [photos.google.com](http://photos.google.com).
2. At the top right, click **Upload** and then select Google Drive.
3. Find and select your photos.
4. Click Upload.

source:[Add photos & videos from Google Drive to Google Photos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?p=drivebanner2_photosdrivearticle&hl=en&visit_id=637119982228604650-2010239759&rd=1)